# Using Ruby, what is the most efficient way to get the content type of a given URL?

Tags: ruby, content-type

What is the most efficient way to get the content-type of a given URL using Ruby?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what I'd do if I want simple code:

```
require 'open-uri'
str = open('http://example.com')
str.content_type #=> "text/html"
```

The big advantage is it follows redirects.

If you're checking a bunch of URLs you might want to call `close` on the handles after you've found what you want.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `open-uri` :)

Found this blog post as a result. Quite handy: http://juretta.com/log/2006/08/13/ruby_net_http_and_open-uri/

Comment: Open-URI is a great little tool when you want to handle URLs transparently, whether they are "file:", "ftp:" or "http:". It handles timeouts and redirects also, so it's good for most things I do, unless I need fine-grained control over a connection, then I'll either drop to Net::HTTP, or use something like Typhoeus or Curb or one of those gems.

Comment: To follow redirections, you may need to use https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/open_uri_redirections

Comment: This saved me many more hours of working on a connection refused on port 80. Thank you!

Comment: Downside is that you have to download the whole target as a tempfile to get its type. :/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) library.

```
require 'net/http'

response = nil
uri, path = 'google.com', '/'
Net::HTTP.start(uri, 80) { |http| response = http.head(path) }
p response['content-type']
```