# Ruby: Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type

I am trying to check if the content type of the resource on my server at s3 has a valid image/jpeg content type. I used the code from[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543629/verifying-a-remote-image-is-actually-an-image-file-in-ruby) but I keep getting the:

> ```
>  Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
>    Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80
> ```

The link to my s3 image is as:

> https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cu-prototype-content/course-content/user-profile-images/BillSKenney-128.jpg

Is there something I need to change in my code?

Comment: I have used the SSL support answer in the link for https support

Comment: Using open-uri worked for me! [From here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400728/using-ruby-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-given-ur